# How to resolve TNS error in Oracle when using an ODBC DSN

Tags: oracle

I have come across this error when I was trying to insert data from front end (using JSP) to back end (Oracle 10g):

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154:
                       TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

**Steps followed:**

1. went to Microsoft ODBC
2. User DSN
3. Enter DNS ,TNS SERVICE NAME, USERID
4. When I click on "Test connection", the result was "Connection Successfull"

When I run my frontend JSP which has a text box and a button, I get the error mentioned above when I click on the button.

Comment: Is the frontend running under a different account to the one you're using to test the connection? Is the DSN set up for user not machine?

Comment: yes front end is running in one machine , and the database i'm using is stored else where ..and i have setup DSN where i have frontend

Comment: PeteH's question asked you about the user, not the computer. Is the user you used to create the DSN the same as the user running whatever app server you're using for your JSP pages?

Comment: @MAT: yes both are same please help me out with solution

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your tns files (tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora) are in a certain directory that is readable by all users.  for example "/oracle/network/admin/"
Make sure that all your users and processes that need to work with the database[s] have the environt variable TNS_ADMIN defined with the value "/oracle/network/admin/".
Doing so gives a good chance that all processes look to the same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

JSP's will run under the account used by the web server process.
A **User** DSN is only available to the account that creates it.
I would fully expect these two accounts to be different.

Try creating a **System** DSN instead.
That will be available to *any* account.